# Location for amcharts javascript files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, amcharts

Im trying to get amcharts to work. If I add the following code to my application layout, then the charts render perfectly:

```
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If on the other hand, as documented on their website, I place the amcharts js files in `app/assets/javascripts/amcharts` and include `//= require amcharts/amcharts`, then nothing is displayed. No errors are generated on the console. The amcharts code is also present if I inspect the element and click on the `application.js` reference. I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming amcharts are not part of a gem. Try

```
//= require_tree amcharts
```

That should pull all the js files in that folder.